# Python QRCODE save to folder

Tags: python, image

How can I save `img` to a specific folder?
I tried `img.save(path, format="PNG")` but it doesn't work.

```py
def generate_qr_code(url):
    qr = qrcode.QRCode(
        version=1,
        error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,
        box_size=15,
        border=5,
    )
    qr.add_data(url)
    path = ('./static/image')
    qr.make(fit=True)
    img = qr.make_image(fill='black', back_color='white')
    temp = BytesIO()
    img.save(path, format="PNG")
    qr_img = base64.b64encode(temp.getvalue())
    return qr_img
```

Comment: Is `img` an object from `PIL`? Which module are you using? Is it [`qrcode`](https://pypi.org/project/qrcode/)?
Also, is there any particular error being displayed?

Comment: I can now assume with enough confidence that you're using `qrcode` and, probably you should focus on `path`. You're saving a file named "image" into the `static/` folder (N.B. you are **not** saving a "image.png", but a file with no extension). But I don't know if that was the problem, please try to edit and implement your question so that it would include an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use path = ('absolute path where you want to save your QR Code File')

i.e - path = ('C:\\Users\\Omii\\Desktop\\QR.png')

Use Always Double Backslash